# How do I get the attributes using a group id?

Tags: attributes, query, group

I want to generate a query, which returns me all of the  attributes from a specific group.
In the image below you can see the wanted result:D 
[image]

This is my try:

```
select ea.attribute_code from eav_attribute ea
inner join eav_entity_attribute eav
on ea.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id
inner join eav_entity_type t
on ea.entity_type_id = t.entity_type_id
where eav.attribute_group_id = 26 
and t.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
```

26 is the General id.

What should i change with my query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [How to get the all attributes that belongs to a attribute group in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898607/how-to-get-the-all-attributes-that-belongs-to-a-attribute-group-in-magento)

```
$groupId = 26;
$attributesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$attributesCollection->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId);
```

Then to get the sql

```
echo $attributesCollection->getSelect()
```

or

```
echo $attributesCollection->getSelect()->__toString()
```

Comment: thx man, how do you know about this piece of code ? :)